# Which tense is better in a timeline? "2001: establishment of an R&D center" vs. "2001: establishing an R&D center"

Tags: tense, present-participles, time-reference

Imagine that we have a corporate website with a timeline of the company's history:

> 2003: **Construction** of a finished dosage forms plant
>   2004: **Establishment** of an R&D center at the Moscow Genetics University
>   2005: **Launch** of an original drug product for combination therapy of   urogenital infections

My main question is: would it be okay to use the gerund-participle form? Like this:

> 2003: **Constructing** a finished dosage forms plant
>   2004: **Establishing** an R&D center at the Moscow Genetics University
>   2005: **Launching** an original drug product for combination therapy of urogenital infections

P.S.

While I was writing the question, I thought - maybe it is better to use the form "*COMPANY does* something"?

> 2003: **Company launches** new finished dosage forms plant
>   2004: **Company establishes** an R&D center at the Moscow Genetics University
>   2005: **Company launches** an original drug product for combination therapy of   urogenital infections

Comment: I prefer #1 or #3. To me #2 doesn't read as a series of gerunds, it reads as an awkward list of verbs missing their subjects. #3 might be good for a corporate document where repeating the name hammers the brand home, unless seeing **Company** over and over feels too repetitive.

Comment: Or {noun phrase}{verb}, e.g. Finish dosage forms plant comes on line. R&D Center established.  Original drug launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a corporate website, I would prefer the third option (Company launches...) but I would like to see it be a complete sentence and the company name in place of "Company" (you might already be intending to do that, but I wanted to mention it just in case you weren't).

The purpose of the timeline (I'm assuming) is to engage potential clients. I think listing the events without explaining a little bit about why that event was important enough to be included on the timeline isn't going to do that well.

Here are some examples of corporate timelines I think are well done:

[Charles Schwab Company History](https://www.aboutschwab.com/about/history)
[Ford Motor Company Timeline](https://corporate.ford.com/history.html)

You'll notice that the timelines above both use full sentences and active voice. I think this sort of thing is much easier to write and more engaging.

Answer (score 1):

#1 (noun phrase without verb) is fine.
#2 (gerund form) is not optimal, because the "-ing" form suggests an ongoing activity rather than the completion of one.
#3 ("Company" + verb in present) is okay, but repetitive.

Another option is general noun phrase (not always "Company") + verb, where the verb will often (but not always) be passive. This option could be mixed with #3 to make it less repetitive.

Answer (score 1):

I have seldom come across what you labeled the 'gerund-participle' in such cases. To me, and of course, the commonest way to express the milestones is what you added lately i.e. "The company does..."

It also goes *fine* with the word 'company' omitted. Said that, the first version is also okay. When you mention the year and put the *semicolon*, it means that now you are describing the event as *a statement* which means it'll be either like *'Company launches...'* or *'Launch of...'*

Answer (score 1):

It will usually depend on what you want to show on the time line.
Usually timelines will show **milestones** (completion of tasks) and not so much work in progress (your gerund form).